# python3 command not found for EC2 non root user

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, path, python-3.7

I want to know how to add a python3.7 path for non root unix user on EC2.

I created an EC2 instance and logged in via ssh. And I created a user called `jpx` by `adduser jpx`. So my home directory has `ec2-user` and  `jpx` sub directories.

As a root user, I installed python3.7, following [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-amazon-linux/). Basically, I followed these steps:

```
yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel
cd /opt
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
sudo rm /usr/src/Python-3.7.9.tgz
```

As a result, my python3.7 was installed at `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`.

Questions:

1. As a root user, I was able to add `/usr/local/bin/` to my `PATH` in the `bash_profile`. So now the command `python3.7` works. But I want to set the command `python3` instead of `python3.7`, so that I can run `python3 app.py` instead of `python3.7 app.py`. How can I do this?
2. As a user `jpx`, I cannot run the command `python3.7`. It returns `bash: python3.7: command not found`. When I print `echo $PATH`, indeed its' `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and the python3.7 path is not included. As a linux beginner I want to understand why this happens. And what is the solution? Not only python3, but also I need to install `pip`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

1. You can link the executable file

cd /usr/local/bin

ln -s python3.7 python3

2. Add the path to the user home .bashrc

vi /home/jpx/.bashrc

Add the following line

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

Logout and login again

Comment: That helped. Thanks!